# How to query SQLAlchemy/PostgreSQL table for existence of an object where PK is UUID

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, uuid, querying

Apologies if this is poorly phrased as I'm pretty new to SQLAlchemy. Suppose I have the following setup:

```
class Student(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'student'
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    name =  Column(String(50), nullable=False)
```

...and I create a new Student and add it to the table:

```
new_student = Student(name="Nick")
session.add(new_student)
session.commit()
```

Assuming that primary key is solely the UUID, how can I check the table for the existence of the specific object referenced by `new_student`? Is it possible to do something like:

```
student = session.query(Student).filter(new_student)
```

Everything I've seen in my searches requires you to use a table column, but the only guaranteed unique column in my table is the UUID, which I don't know until after it's created.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If I remember correctly, `new_student.id` might get set by `session.add()` and `commit()`. I think SQLAlchemy issues an `INSERT ... RETURNING` query to accomplish that. Don't have time to test that myself.

Comment: Calling `session.flush()` after `session.add(...)` should set the primary key value on the object.